# Would this work for a modification check in my program?

Tags: security

Sorry if this is sort of vague but i'm wanting to protect my program by checking for modifications in its code to say, bypass a security measure, such as jumping over the check, i would like to prevent this and i have a few ideas on how to do so such as setting each function to set a variable to something, then check if it is set during runtime, would such a thing be secure?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your definition of secure. The more complex you make your checks the harder it will be for an attacker to crack.

Signing your application then checking the signature on startup would be another option but an attacker could easily bypass the check. Checking in multiple places will make it a little harder to defeat.